# AWS/s3 & Paperclip images not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use AWS & Paperclip for user uploads on my deployed app on Heroku, but I keep getting this error when I try to upload a post with an image attached to it:

**

```
015-08-12T16:30:14.773630+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: Started POST "/posts" for 24.52.240.16 at 2015-08-12 16:30:14 +0000
2015-08-12T16:30:14.956915+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: sh: 1:
2015-08-12T16:30:14.999032+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: sh: 1:
2015-08-12T16:30:15.701055+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: sh: 1:
2015-08-12T16:30:15.664880+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: Command :: PATH=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/e4b70d27eba59aa7021fe4c7a3f37f0920150812-129-lzw5hm.jpeg[0]'
2015-08-12T16:30:15.701148+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: FilesImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin: not found
2015-08-12T16:30:15.701215+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr:
2015-08-12T16:30:15.668736+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: sh: 1:
2015-08-12T16:30:15.668859+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: FilesImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin: not found
2015-08-12T16:30:15.668921+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr:
2015-08-12T16:30:15.698923+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: Command :: PATH=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:$PATH; convert '/tmp/e4b70d27eba59aa7021fe4c7a3f37f0920150812-129-lzw5hm.jpeg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/52d7f5bb59811ac88441c8968f792bbd20150812-129-1g4pubj'
2015-08-12T16:30:17.310929+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: Command :: PATH=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/e4b70d27eba59aa7021fe4c7a3f37f0920150812-129-mnm95q.jpeg'
2015-08-12T16:30:17.314951+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: sh: 1:
2015-08-12T16:30:17.315044+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr: FilesImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin: not found
2015-08-12T16:30:17.315109+00:00 app[web.1]: App 113 stderr:
2015-08-12T16:30:17.571944+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: [paperclip] saving /posts/images/000/000/048/original/firefighters.jpeg
2015-08-12T16:30:17.947443+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: [AWS S3 403 0.35544 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"apolloportalinc",:content_length=>2194514,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: firefighters.jpeg,:key=>"posts/images/000/000/048/original/firefighters.jpeg") AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied
2015-08-12T16:30:17.950079+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3172ms
2015-08-12T16:30:17.947479+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout:
2015-08-12T16:30:17.966625+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/posts" host=lit-dawn-3200.herokuapp.com request_id=ae1674d7-f249-4e40-b4cf-6228fbbf3f82 fwd="24.52.240.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=43027ms status=500 bytes=1829
2015-08-12T16:30:17.952777+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout:
2015-08-12T16:30:17.952841+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:41:in `create'
2015-08-12T16:30:17.952818+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout: AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied):
2015-08-12T16:30:17.952884+00:00 app[web.1]: App 129 stdout:
```

**

Here's what's in my paperclip.rb:

```
require "paperclip"

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16'
Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

and I have the right code in my production.rb, according to this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does your code upload to AWS in development? Or is the error only on heroku?

Comment: i didn't set it up for development... do I need to do that?

Comment: well, running your rails app locally can help you debug stuff for sure, but it's unrelated to the question. I'll write up an answer to get you started.

Comment: okay, cool. i'll try setting it up for dev as well.

Comment: so I got the error: missing required :bucket option when I started my rails server after added AWS stuff to development.rb. The error points to my show.html.erb view and highlights <div class ="post-image">
                 <% if post.image.url %>
                   <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url), post %>
                 <% else %>
                   <%= image_tag("BG2.jpg") %>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like from the error, you aren't authenticating with AWS on your heroku app. That's most likely because you haven't set your `ENV` variables. You need to run the following terminal commands.

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME="thisisthenameofmybucket"
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="myaccesskey"
heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="my_secret_access_key_here"
```

So you'll get all those values from AWS. Then run those commands in the terminal and your ENV variables will be set. That's kinda step one. Then you need to see what error comes after that.

Comment: I set my env variables already - and I tried again just now and got the same error.

Comment: Does it matter that my key id & secret key are for an IAM user?